# Initializing objects using this operator in constructors

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, constructor

As I was trying to implement code first approach using repository patterns in MVC, I have come across some difficulties as below:

I have a Interface that have few methods declared as below :

```
public interface IRepository
    {
        User Getuserdetail(int UserId);
        void Save(User Obj);
        void delete(int Userid);
        void update(User user);
    }
```

Then I have a Repository class which could be using the above interface to define all the methods and will create a seperate layer of Entity Framework:

```
public class Repository : IRepository
    {
            RepoDBContext _context;
            Repository(RepoDBContext Context)
            {
                this._context = Context;
            }

        public User Getuserdetail(int Userid)
        {
            var user = _context.User.Where(m => m.id == Userid).FirstOrDefault();
            return user;
        }
        public void Save(User user)
        {
            _context.User.Add(user);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
}
```

Now could you please check the constructor of this class. The variable this constructor is initializing is type of "RepoDBContext" and the reference type it is using to assign it is also of "RepoDBContext". Is it internally performing like below?

```
RepoDBContext _context=new RepoDBContext();
```

My RepoDBContext class is below:

```
  public class RepoDBContext : DbContext
            {
                public DbSet<User> User { get; set; }
            }
```

Moreover if is the right way to perform then how will i have to call this class in my controller to do some functionality over my user interface. Please guide regarding the same and please don't mind my english. Thanks

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Are you asking if assigning a parameter to a field is equivalent to instantiating a new instance of that type?  (it isn't)

Comment: yes Sir. You got it.

Comment: Are you planning to use any dependency injection containers in your application? Another point I would make, is that you probably don't need to expect a dbContext instance in your Repository constructor. Create the instance of the dbContext inside your repository. It will be the only "layer" in your program who has to deal with it.

Comment: At this point I am just trying to implement and understand the repository but yes ultimately I would prefer to go for implementing DI.  Could you pl suggest.

Comment: I will scratch some code here, I'll post later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you already have an answer to the question  `does assigning a parameter to a field is equivalent to instantiating a new instance of that type` as state in the comments and in the answer by Oskar and Kirk.

But I just want go further and try to answer this another question of yours: `how will I have to call this class in my controller to do some functionality over my user interface.`.

If you create your structure using the Repository pattern, you wouldn't want your controllers to handle instances of your DbContext class, because if they do, what is the benefit of having a separated repository layer then? A common pattern that I see people using and I use it myself in several apps is something as follows:

**IUserRepository**

```
public interface IUserRepository
{
    User GetUserDetail(int userId);
    void Save(User user);
    void Delete(int userId);
    void Update(User user);
}
```

**UserRepository**

```
public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
{
    public User GetUserDetail(int userId)
    {
        using(var _context = new RepoDBContext())
        {
            return _context.User.Where(m => m.id == userId).FirstOrDefault();
        }       
    }

    //other implementations here..
}
```

Then, you create another layer which will be your Business layer, similar to the Repository.

**IUserBusiness**

```
public interface IUserBusiness
{
    User GetUserDetail(int userId);
    void Save(User user);
    void Delete(int userId);
    void Update(User user);
}
```

**UserBusiness**

```
public class UserBusiness : IUserBusiness
{
    private readonly IUserRepository userRepository;

    //CTOR receives a Repository instance via DI
    public UserBusiness(IUserRepository userRepository)
    {
        this.userBusiness = userBusiness;
    }

    public User GetUserDetail(int userId)
    {
        //Call repository to get User details
        return this.userRepository.GetUserDetail(userId);
    }

    //other implementations here
}
```

**UserController** (example)

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
    private readonly IUserBusiness userBusiness;

    //Controller receives a UserBusinnes instance via DI
    public UserController(IUserBusiness userBusiness)
    {
        this.userBusiness = userBusiness;
    }

    public ActionResult GetDetail(int userId)
    {
        //Call your "repository" to get user data
        var userDetail = userBusiness.GetUserDetail(userId);

        //more logic here
    }
}
```

See the difference? Each layer of your application is concerned with one thing. You controller **request data** to your **business layer**, which may apply some business rules or validations, and finally call your **repository layer** which knows how to talk to the database or other storage. Your controller doesn't have any concern about how to create instances of database class or make queries. It just receive a request, ask for data and returns back to the caller.

Answer (score 1):

No, assigning an existing instance of RepoDBContext to a variable is NOT the same as calling `new RepoDBContext()`. Assignment is just assignment and will not allocate new objects.

Off-topic:
Please also consider that C# coding guidelines suggest that method parameters should be named `likeThis` (that is, with initial lower case letter). This will make you code more consistent with other .Net code libraries.